# How to change a hook in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This code is working good.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','myfunction');

function myfunction(){

echo 'something text';

}
```

But I want check first if `$product` is type variable and then change the hook to `'woocommerce_before_single_variation'`.

How can I change this? and check if product is variable?

Comment: `woocommerce_before_single_variation` fires only for variable products in the cart. No need for an if statement or anything else. Just use that hook. See http://hookr.io/themes/evolve/3.7.2/files/woocommerce-single-product-add-to-cart-variable/

Comment: You don't replace a hook with another, you just use another hook: `add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','myfunction');`. 
The hook is used on the _single product page:_ https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: Thanks for reply,but I want to change hook because  when I echo in variable product it is print twice with hook 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button'. But when I change hook to 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' it is print ok(but not ok when product is simple).Any idea why that print twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_variation','myfunction');
function myfunction(){
global $post, $product, $woocommerce_loop;
    if( $product->has_child() ) 
echo 'something text';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','myfunction2');
function myfunction2(){
global $post, $product, $woocommerce_loop;
    if(! $product->has_child() ) 
echo 'something text';
}
```

Although the text should not be added twice. So I suppose it would be better to find why it happens in your case.